# Connect Firebird Database with Entity Framework model - Connection Failed

Tags: entity-framework, firebird, firebird-3.0, firebird-embedded

I want to connect the Firebird database with Entity Framework Model. Completed the successful installation and created the database. But, I am facing the issue 'Index was outside the bounds of the array' while connecting the database. Refer the below image.
[image]

- Visual Studio 2015
- Firebird client version 4.10.0.0
- DDEX Provider version 3.0.2.0
- Firebird setup v3.0.4

I followed the steps as suggested in this link. But I choose 'Embedded Server' as server type.  https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fbdevgd-en/html/fbdg30-efw-vs-prepare.html

After done the above configurations, I faced the below.

```
Unable to load dll 'fbembed': The specified module could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT:0x8007007E)
```

So, I set 'fbclient.dll' as a client library in the advanced option. After that I am facing this error

```
Index was outside the bounds of the array
```

[image]

What I have done wrong here? Please correct me.

Comment: What version of Visual Studio, what version of the Firebird ado.net provider, what version of the Firebird DDEX provider? Exactly what steps did you follow to get to this error?

Comment: while probably not related here, "NONE" for Charset is dangerous settings

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, Now I have added those details in the description. I followed the steps as suggested in this link https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/fbdevgd-en/html/fbdg30-efw-vs-prepare.html

Comment: @Arioch'The I tried the charset 'UTF-8' and that too not working. But I dont know what should be the correct charset settings here.

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to a more recent version of the Firebird ado.net provider?

Comment: @KathirSubramaniam UTF-8 is ok, or any other where exist all letters you and your clients might need. Just Firebird need to know to which encoding to translate texts when shuffling between your program and database.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, I tried with the latest Firebird version (6.4.0), but 'Firebird Data Sources' was not listed in Data Sources list. So, I again downgraded them to v4.10.x and now I am facing that previous error 'Index was outside the bounds of the array'. I set 'fbclient.dll' as client library in 'Advanced' option. Is that correct?

Comment: @KathirSubramaniam That is only used when you use an embedded connection, and the default doesn't use that. I suggest that you take this to the firebird-net-provider Google group.